# Spyne/Python/Soap. Add xsi:type to AnyDict

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, spyne, xsi

Im using Spyne & I try to add xsi:type="xsd:string" to my AnyDict result in response .

Now i have this one:

```
<soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://localhost/nusoap">
   <soap11env:Body>
      <tns:ERespons>
         <tns:EResponsRecord>
            <state>failed</state>
            <err_msg>Nastala chyba</err_msg>
         </tns:EResponsRecord>
      </tns:ERespons>
   </soap11env:Body>
</soap11env:Envelope>
```

But i need to get :

```
<soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://localhost/nusoap">
   <soap11env:Body>
      <tns:ERespons>
         <tns:EResponsRecord>
            <state xsi:type="xsd:string">failed</state>
            <err_msg xsi:type="xsd:string">Nastala chyba</err_msg>
         </tns:EResponsRecord>
      </tns:ERespons>
   </soap11env:Body>
</soap11env:Envelope>
```

My Service:

```
class AddEntryEC(ServiceBase):
        EntryObject.__namespace__ = 'Entry.soap'
        __out_header__ = EntryObject

        @rpc(
                AnyDict,
                _out_message_name = 'ERespons',
                _out_variable_name = 'EResponsRecord',
                _returns=AnyDict
        )

        def AddEntry(ctx, data):

                data = get_object_as_dict(data)
                try :
                        ctx.app.db_tool.set_args(data)
                        res = ctx.app.db_tool.insert_data()
                        
                        return res

                except Exception as e:
                        logging.exception(e) 
                        return  {'state' : 'failed',
                                'err_msg' : 'Nastala chyba'}
```

My app declaration :

```
application = MyApplication([AddEntryEC], 'http://localhost/nusoap', in_protocol=Soap11(validator='soft'), out_protocol=Soap11())
```

Do u have some idea to help me with solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AnyDict` can't handle this use case -- it simply doesn't have any means to store the additional metadata. You must set your return type as `AnyXml` and return an `Element` object with any desired attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Burak , my code now:

```
@rpc(
  AnyDict,
  _out_message_name = 'ERespons',
  _returns=AnyXml
)
    
def AddEntry(ctx, data):
  data = get_object_as_dict(data)
  qname = etree.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "type")
  root = etree.Element('EResponsRecord')
    
  s = etree.SubElement(root, 'state')
  s.attrib[qname] = 'string'
    
  e = etree.SubElement(root, 'err_msg')
  e.attrib[qname] = 'string'
    
  try:
    ctx.app.db_tool.set_args(data)
    res = ctx.app.db_tool.insert_data()
    
    s.text = res['state']
    e.text = res['err_msg']             
  except Exception as e:
    logging.exception(e) 
    
    s.text = 'failed' 
    e.text = 'Nastala chyba'
    
  return root
```